# Collectionview cell didselect is not navigating faster to a new page

Tags: ios

I have a collection view in my app main dashboard, but when i click (didSelectCell) on it, it is taking long time to navigate to a new screen. Is there any code that can speed this up?
Thanks in advance.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    let nextViewController:viewcontroller = viewcontroller(nibName:"viewcontroller",bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
})
```

Comment: `didSelectCell` isn't called on main thread already?

Comment: Is it still "slow" if you get rid of the `DispatchQueue.main.async`, and just use those two lines of code?

Comment: The animation should take about 0.3 seconds. What you are probably experiencing is that it takes a long time to initialise and load the view for your pushed view controller before the animation can even start. You need to examine what properties are initialised and what code is run before the view controller can start to be displayed and animated. To test this theory change your push to not animate. Any delay you see is the time it takes to initialise and load the view.

Comment: @DonMag yes, Even if I get rid of DispatchQueue.main.async, it is still slow.

Comment: @Aagamvora - ok, then... as Geoff said, it is probably whatever code you have running in `viewDidLoad()` of the controller you are pushing. We need to see that code to try and help you.